# 3Scale custom policy matching path param in the URI

Tags: liquid, liquid-template, 3scale

I am using 3Scale's edge limiting policy to impose rate limiting for my API and having the following endpoints

```
GET /v1/user
GET /v1/user/{name}
GET /v1/user/{name}/{organization}
```

For the first endpoint configuring rate limit is pretty straight forward

```
Algorithm Used: Fixed Window Limiters
Window Size: 60 seconds
Operations:
  op: ==
  right: /v1/user
  right_type: plain text
  left: {{ uri }}
  left_type: liquid
```

But for the next two endpoints, I am unable to set the right value of the Operations since these contains path parameters.

How to define the path parameter in the URL in Operations?